# Replace image with its alt text?

Tags: images, filters, regex, wp-kses

I have a WordPress post with lots of inline HTML images.

I want to output my HTML in such a way that the existing:

`<p>Here's my cat: <img src="example.jpg" alt="A photo of lovely black cat."></p>`

Becomes:

`<p>Here's my cat: A photo of lovely black cat.</p>`

I know that I can use `wp_kses($html, array( "img" => array( "alt"=>array() ) ) );` to preserve the `<img>` and `alt`. But I *only* want the alt.

Ideally, I'd like it to render as `(Image. A photo of a lovely black cat.)` - but I thought I'd see if there was a simple way of just getting the alt first.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `the_content` filter for this. Something like this...

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse418925_replace_images_with_alt' );
function wpse418925_replace_images_with_alt( $content ) {
    // If you need to *only* do this on one post, check that we're in that post.
    // $desired_post can be an ID, post title, slug, or an array of any of those.
    if ( is_single( $desired_post ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace( '/<img.*(alt="[^"]+")[^>]*>/', '(Image. $1)', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

... might do what you're looking for.

### Notes

- This code is *untested*. Try it out on a local installation or a test site *first*.
- This code is meant as a starting point only. In particular, it's likely you'll have to tweak the regular expression to suit your situation.
- `preg_replace()` can be a "heavy" function, ie, time-intensive. You might want to consider caching the post's modified content to an option or to post_meta.

### References

- [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)
- [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)